# jQuery AJAX callback function issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple voting mechanism Im trying to block out. I got some help earlier and it works on its own but I'm trying to do it with an ajax callback - i get the returned data but the funciton isn't firing for some reason (although it works with a simple alert as the callback function) but it's not incrementing the numbers.
Here's the simplified HTML

```
<form name="vote" id="vote" method="post" action="PHP/success.php">
    <a class="vote">Good</a><input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
    <a class="vote">Bad</a><input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
</form>
```

Here is the dummy PHP (PHP/success.php) that only performs an echo at this point

```
<?php
    echo('ok');
?>
```

and my click function

```
$(".vote").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PHP/success.php",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data=="ok") {
                var input = $(this).next(".qty");
                input.val(parseFloat(input.val()) + 1);
            } else {
        alert('error');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

again if i replace the (data="ok") var and function with an alert it works fine. 
thx

Comment: Could just be whitespace on `data`, try `$.trim(data) == 'ok'` instead.

Comment: What happens if i click `Bad`? `$(this).next(".qty")` will fail in that case.

Comment: @muistooshort nope. this is puzzling...it looks right doesn't it?

Comment: @jSang it seems to work when it's not in the context of an ajax call http://dirtybirddesignlab.com/Wronglish/test.html

Comment: Sorry, i missed the input tag, my bad. BTW could you show us the exact value of the ajax call `data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `var input = $(this).next(".qty");` outside.

```
$(".vote").click(function() {
    var input = $(this).next(".qty");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PHP/success.php",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data=="ok") {            
                input.val(parseFloat(input.val()) + 1);
            } else {
        alert('error');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: awesome. always had issues with the "think globally act locally" stuff. I appreciate it man.

Answer (score 4):

i think problem is with this line.

```
var input = $(this).next(".qty");
```

$(this) is not giving the clicked element there.

if you replace it by

```
var input = $(".vote").next(".qty");
```

the function works.

**EDIT:**

I tried with this and it worked.

```
 $(".vote").click(function() {
                      var kk = $(this);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "a.php",
    success: function(data) {

    if (data=="ok") {

            var input = kk.next(".qty");
            input.val(parseFloat(input.val()) + 1);
        } else {
    alert('error');
        }


    }
});
});
```

Comment: That seems right, but you should probably save a reference to `this` outside the callback instead - your answer won't work correctly if there are multiple `.vote` elements.

Comment: @nrabinowitz so just move the var kk = $(this) up above the .ajax call, similar to xdazz's answer right? that would make it global correct?

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign - yup, that's what I was thinking.